# How to stop dynamically changing padding of body in an html web page

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-modal

In my html page I have one link on which each time if I  click I will get a modal pop up.
If I close this modal the padding of body tag is increased, it is continuously increasing. I don't know how to stop it.

Like before I open modal pop up the body tag will be like this

```
<body class="sidebar-mini skin-purple modal-open" >
```

after I click and close  the pop up it becomes like this

```
<body class="sidebar-mini skin-purple modal-open" style="padding-right:19px;" >
```

and it keeps on increasing each time we open modal pop up and close it.
How to stop it?

Comment: Provide the JavaScript for the modal

Comment: i am using bootstrap

Comment: Have you added another JavaScript to your website that may effect the modal JavaScript?

Comment: body.modal-open { padding-right: 0px !important}

Comment: if you can debug with Firefox dev tools, you might find an event listener attached to the body element. You can then debug and see where/how the padding is done.

Comment: This is a Javascript error, as such you absolutely need to include some Javascript.

Answer (score 2):

i just removed the bootstrap.min.js file link and it is working fine

Answer (score 2):

may be other java-scripts files that are present in your file e.g. bootstrap.js may be clashing and creating problem for u . delete them and then check.